# is there a way to solve utf-8' codec

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to read csv file in pandas

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/GUVI PROJECTS/placement tasks/DDW_B18_0800_NIC_FINAL_STATE_RAJASTHAN-2011.csv")
```

but i am getting error as

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 23483: invalid start byte
```

How do I read the file?

Comment: `pandas` assumes that the file is utf-8 encoded, but once it hit the 23483rd byte in the file, it didn't map to utf-8. Usually that means that the file was orignally written in a Windows code page encoding. We can't really know without the file itself, but you could add `encoding="cp1252"` to the `read_csv` call. That's a common encoding in the USA and Europe.

Comment: Voting to close since no MRE was given.

Comment: do u want me to upload the file tdelaney provide the entire syntax on how to add encoding="cp1252" to the read_csv

Comment: That code point is a windows fancy quote. Are you sure your file is actually utf-8?

Comment: You can ignore the error by adding `encoding_errors="replace"` in the `read_csv` method. This way you can see the dataframe and then check whats going on. You can find all the `encoding_errors` options [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers).

Answer (score 0):

```
filepath="C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/GUVI PROJECTS/placement tasks/DDW_B18_0800_NIC_FINAL_STATE_RAJASTHAN-2011.csv"

f=open(filepath,encoding="utf-8",errors="surrogateescape")

df1 = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: geekay   it shows an error   Input In [17]
    f=open(filepath,encoding="utf-8",errors="errors="surrogateescape")
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: There is a typo...correct it at your end...errors="surrogatescape" .....

Comment: geekay still it shows an error

Comment: LookupError: unknown error handler name 'surrogatescape'

Comment: i did this in colab also . it is showing me an error

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 23483: invalid start byte

Comment: please make that errors="surrogateescape".        two e's in it. if still an error . try  encoding="cp1252" instead of utf-8